# How to calculate RAM usage of a image when decoded

Tags: image, image-processing, ram

How do I can determine the ammount of RAM used by a image when loaded?

For standard I think that a image size on RAM will be width * height * PIXEL_FORMAT, where PIXEL_FORMAT will be RGB (3 bits) or ARGB (4 bits)

But for my calc, a 64*64(ARGB) image will have 2MB of memory usage, that I'm pretty sure is a wrong result.

Is a decoded image loaded as a compressed image and decompressed for drawing/drawed compressed through decompressers algorithms?

Comment: It will be a minimum of width * height * bytes per pixel. So a 64x64 RGBA image will require 64*64*4 bytes or 16kB. Some formats use 2 bytes for each of RGB and A. Some use 4 bytes for each of RGB and A. Some libraries expand into a block of contiguous memory, some expand into 2-D arrays and need additional pointers for the rows. Some formats (BMP) pad the ends of line to a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: Ohh.. trues,, my 2MB is actually 2KB. Post this as an answer so i can give it a UP